# undefined method `delete_if' for String on ActiveRecord::Base saving with Device gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have such code:

```
# User - typical class of ActiveRecord::Base 
user1 = User.first
user2 = User.last

user2.save
# return true

user1.save
   (1.2ms)  BEGIN
   (1.4ms)  ROLLBACK
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_if' for #<String:0x000000073a9790>

user1.errors.count
# 0 errors returned!
```

I can not reproduce this bug locally, only on server.

What it is?

How it is possible to get more info about this magical bug and fix it?

**Added:**
Seems it issue with devise gem because this workaround possible:

```
user1.tokens = nil
user.save
# return true
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace returned or just the error message? Without a stack trace, I would search the whole codebase for the string `delete_if`. That should lead you to the place at which the error is raised and why it is raised.

Comment: Sounds like you have a string where you should have a hash or an array. Is it the field `tokens` on one of the users?

Comment: setting the user tokens to nil solved the issue for me.  thank you for the workaround!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use "save!" instead "save"? It will clarify about the error at the AR commit moment.

Try to compare two objects, see what is different between user1 and user2 records.

If it seems that is a devise problem, you can unpack the gem and search the "delete_if" to debug purposes.